# Where did my "Improve this question" link go?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, anonymous

I wanted to propose a significant edit to [a closed question on The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/9808/316) to try and get it reopened, but because it was so significant I wanted the OP to review the edit first.

I used an Incognito window to access the site and proposed the edit as an Anonymous User, with an editing note that specifically asked for reviewers to ignore the edit and leave it for the OP to review.

When I submitted the edit, I expected it to give me the alert that it had been submitted for peer review and to show me the edited question, but instead it took me back to the original question with no warning, and now none of the questions on The Workplace show an "Improve this Question link".

In addition, the Review queue for the site doesn't show my edit.

I tried hitting the Back button and resubmitting the edit, however now it takes me to a 404 page.

Did I trigger some kind of IP auto-ban on suggesting edits for the site with such a significant edit?

And if not, what happened to the `[improve this question]` link? It still exists on other SE sites, just not on The Workplace.

For the record, the suggested edit was this:

> **What value is there at working for a big-name tech firm from a career
>   point of view?**
>
> I am currently considering 2 job offers:
>
> 1. At a big tech company in the valley
> 2. A small local midwest development shop
>
> I am wondering if working at Big Tech Company opens up a lot of
>   different doors for future jobs just because of the name, and if there
>   is value in working at the Big Tech firm from a strictly career point
>   of view?

With a review note of:

> NOTE TO REVIEWERS: Please leave this edit suggestion for the OP to
>   review. Hi MidwestDev, I'd like to propose this change to your
>   question to try and get it reopened. If you're OK with this change, go
>   ahead and Approve the edit, but if this changes your question too much
>   then feel free to Reject it

I had also planned on leaving a more detailed comment for the OP explaining the purpose of such a dramatic edit, and why the original version was closed while the edited version was appropriate.